# Method overloading of dynamically created Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, overloading

The goal is to overload the `__str__(self)` method of an `Enum` with dynamically created attributes.

A dynamic enum may be created with

[1]:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

A = Enum('A',
         dict(('a_'+some_input, auto())
              for some_input in ['1','2','3']),
         module=__name__)
```

Method overloading may be done with

[2]:

```
class A(Enum):
    a_no_input = auto()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Separatly, both examples work as needed. To combine both I tried:

```
[1]: ...
A.__class__.__str__ = lambda self: str(self.name)
```

But this doesn't alter the output of `print(A.a_1)`.

and

```
class A(Enum):
    def __init__(self):
        super('A',
              dict(('a_' + some_input, auto())
                   for some_input in ['1', '2', '3']),
              module=__name__)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

But this doesn't create static attributes that can be accessed via `A.a_1`.

How do I dynamically create static attributes of an enum and overload the methods of the super class `Enum`?

Comment: can you elaborate on "fail to provide the full functionality"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third code snippet should be:

```
A.__str__ = lambda self: str(self.name)
```

Notice I took `__class__` out.

Comment: Argh, thank you! - Just out of curiosity, is there a possibility to make the second approach work as well?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [2] + [1]. Enumerations can be subclassed if they are empty:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class EnumStr(Enum):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

A = EnumStr('A',
         dict(('a_'+some_input, auto())
              for some_input in ['1','2','3']),
         module=__name__)

print(A.a_1)
```